# SQLDelight select query with when clause where argument is List of Strings

Tags: sql, sqlite, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile, sqldelight

I have a sql query which selects data based on some filter values

```
getFiltered:
SELECT * FROM TaskEntity
WHERE
    CASE WHEN :searchWord IS NOT NULL THEN name LIKE '%' || :searchWord || '%' OR code LIKE '%' || :searchWord || '%' ELSE 1 END
    AND CASE WHEN :gId IS NOT NULL THEN gId = :gId ELSE 1 END
    AND CASE WHEN :assignedUserIds IS NOT NULL THEN assignedUserIds IN (:assignedUserIds) ELSE 1 END
    ORDER BY position ASC
LIMIT :take OFFSET :skip
;
```

and I want to select data based on `assignedUserIds` which is type of `List<String>`.

`TaskEntity` table has field `assignedUserIds Text AS List<String>`

when I'm passing list of ids to the `getFiltered(assignedUserIds = listOf("1","2"))` function it returns 0 records, instead of returning some records, cause some of them has values matching with that params.
I'm assuming something is wrong with that line:
`AND CASE WHEN :assignedUserIds IS NOT NULL THEN assignedUserIds IN (:assignedUserIds) ELSE 1 END`

```
SQLDelight version = "1.5.3"
dialect = "sqlite:3.25"
```

Table definiton

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TaskEntity` (
`id` TEXT NOT NULL,
`code` TEXT NOT NULL,
`name` TEXT NOT NULL,
`sId` TEXT,
`mId` TEXT,
`position` INTEGER AS Int NOT NULL,
`assignedUserIds` Text AS List<String>,

PRIMARY KEY(`id`));
```

Comment: `assignedUserIds` Text AS List<String> is not valid SQL syntax.  In additional, it is very poor design.  A single column in SQL should store a scalar value, not a collection (some SQL flavors do support arrays, but not SQLite AFAIK).

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want to build a flexible prepared statement which has the ability to handle the case where one or more parameters may be null.  You should use something like this version:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM TaskEntity
WHERE
    (name LIKE :searchWord OR :searchWord IS NULL) AND
    (gId = :gId OR :gId IS NULL) AND
    (assignedUserId IN :assignedUserIds OR :assignedUserIds IS NULL)
ORDER BY position;
```

Some comments:

I have reworked the logic such that either the parameter has to match the assertion *or* the parameter has to be left `NULL`.  If the latter be the case, then that entire condition essentially no-ops, and the SQL parser will ignore it and check the remaining conditions.

To `:searchWord` you should bind a string representing the entire `LIKE` expression, e.g. if you wanted to find `banana` anywhere in the `name` column, you would bind `%banana%` from your code.  As for `:assignedUserIds`, it should be valid to use that in an `IS NULL` assertion.  But note that `WHERE col IN (...)` compares a single scalar value against a collection, not a collection against a collection.

Comment: Based on that changes, sqldelight generated class which takes Collection<List<String>> but its adapter still requires List<String> type of adapter

bindString(assignedUserIds.size + 11, assignedUserIds?.let {
            database.TaskEntityAdapter.assignedUserIdsAdapter.encode(it) })
and here encode needs Collection<List<String>>

Comment: should I change the column type of the table from List<String> to Collection<List<String>>?

Comment: dao.getFilteredNew(
      searchWord = null,
      gId = null,
      sId = null,
      assignedUserIds = listOf(listOf("1","2")),
      take = 20,
      skip = 0
    )

Comment: I can't see your entity definitions so I can't comment.

Comment: I have added table definition